# Reviewboard error: rbtools.commands.CommandError: There don't seem to be any diffs

Tags: git, review-board

I'm using ReviewBoard and `rbt post` to post a review request. I issue the following command:

```
rbt post --debug -o 4a6c23e933f753ddb855a8f2a16ae5a0c9bb8ebe..2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66
```

And see the following output:

```
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Subversion repository...
DEBUG:root:Running: svn info --non-interactive
DEBUG:root:Command exited with rc 1: ['svn', 'info', '--non-interactive']
svn: '.' is not a working copy
---
DEBUG:root:Checking for a Git repository...
DEBUG:root:Running: git rev-parse --git-dir
DEBUG:root:Running: git config core.bare
DEBUG:root:Running: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
DEBUG:root:Running: git symbolic-ref -q HEAD
DEBUG:root:Running: git config --get git-p4.port
DEBUG:root:Command exited with rc 1: ['git', 'config', '--get', 'git-p4.port']
---
DEBUG:root:Running: git config --get branch.mybranch.merge
DEBUG:root:Running: git config --get branch.mybranch.remote
DEBUG:root:Running: git config --get remote.origin.url
DEBUG:root:repository info: Path: mort-cake, Base path: , Supports changesets: False
DEBUG:root:Making HTTP GET request to https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/
DEBUG:root:Making HTTP GET request to https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/info/
DEBUG:root:Running: git rev-parse refs/heads/mybranch
DEBUG:root:Running: git merge-base 2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66 origin/mybranch
DEBUG:root:Running: git rev-parse 2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66
DEBUG:root:Running: git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
DEBUG:root:Running: git diff --no-color --full-index --no-ext-diff --ignore-submodules --no-renames 2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66..2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66 -M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rbt", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('RBTools==0.5.5', 'console_scripts', 'rbt')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RBTools-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/rbtools/commands/main.py", line 127, in main
    command.run_from_argv([RB_MAIN] + args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RBTools-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/rbtools/commands/__init__.py", line 158, in run_from_argv
    exit_code = self.main(*args) or 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RBTools-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/rbtools/commands/post.py", line 633, in main
    raise CommandError("There don't seem to be any diffs!")
rbtools.commands.CommandError: There don't seem to be any diffs!
```

Note the real error on the last line.

Now, see where it says:

```
DEBUG:root:Running: git diff --no-color --full-index --no-ext-diff --ignore-submodules --no-renames 2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66..2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66 -M
```

Well, sure, there are no diffs between a revision and itself. But why is ReviewBoard using those revisions anyway? Why isn't it using the ones I supplied?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to get around this so far is to first checkout the commit of the end revision. E.g.

```
git checkout 2d785c5d7b34317e679b20ac112ac7f69074df66
```

This of course puts the repo in a detached HEAD state. But I can then run my command, it succeeds as I expect, and then I can do `git checkout mybranch` to get back to my normal workflow.

Comment: `co` is not a built-in git command, it looks like you've aliased `checkout` as `co`,

Comment: Correct. Thanks for noticing; I'll update it to `checkout` to be clear.

Comment: My buddy nick had the same problem as I did on his computer. My answer here did not fix the situation. However, I then ran a `rbt post` for him on my machine, without using my trick in this answer, and it worked. So I'm not sure what causes the problem.